# ReactJS Multi Dynamic Input Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I need**

I need to 'build' and 'edit' a form with multiple dynamic input. I have a form, but the user can add other input.

**How I do**

I already 'build' form before, first i was use the `ref` to find my content then in second time i was used the `input value` to 'load' my content from the server and added a `state` to 'edit' it.

**The Problem**

Now, for an other form, the user can add more input if he want. So for the 'build ' is not a problem I thinks. 
And for the 'edit' I don't how many input the user added before, so to added the `input value` for view it's ok, but to edit the value I need a `state` and initial it, but i don't know how I can initialized multiple `states` dynamically.

**My basic code**

```
@Component = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        Input1: ''

    handelChange: (e)->
        @setState
            Input1: e.target.value

    render: ->
        `<form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="input" type="text" ref="name" name="name" value={this.state.input1} onChange={this.handelChange}/>
        </form>`
```

(I don't put all the code, but input1 = dataFromServer)

How I can have input2, input3 etc... dynamic ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have several initial state, getInitialState() is called only before the first rendering.

However you can add and complete your state with as many objects as you want even if they were not declared in getInitiaState();

Lets say the user click on a button to add an input

```
handelChange: (e)->
        var newState = this.state;
        newstate["MyNewInput"] = "some initial value field";
        @setState
            newState
```

Something like that should work. Hope it helps, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer! Yes, I thinks that solve my problem! It's the first time I use React and I thought the state is only create on getIniSt, and I don't know we can do `newState = this.state`. Thanks so much, I try that and I tell you if it's solve the problem!

Comment: I was solve the problem using a `state = array` and add the new input value on my array then send my array to the backend. Thanks for help!